# SceneKit Plane Rotation

Tags: ios, scenekit

When I create a plane in `SceneKit`, the normal vector of the plane is the positive z-axis by default. I want to re-orient the plane by using a different normal vector. However, I am not sure how to rotate the plane to the right position, even though I know what the new normal vector should be. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an example that creates a rotation matrix based on an input SCNVector3 'axis' (which would be your target normal).

```
        SCNVector3 tangent0 = [self crossVector: axis: SCNVector3Make(1, 0, 0)];
        if ([self dotVector:tangent0 : tangent0] < 0.001) {
            tangent0 = [self crossVector: axis: SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 0)];
        }
        tangent0 = [self normalizeVector:tangent0];
        SCNVector3 tangent1 = [self normalizeVector: [self crossVector:axis: tangent0]];

        GLKVector4 tangent0GLK = GLKVector4Make(tangent0.x, tangent0.y, tangent0.z, 0);
        GLKVector4 tangent1GLK = GLKVector4Make(tangent1.x, tangent1.y, tangent1.z, 0);
        GLKVector4 axisGLK = GLKVector4Make(axis.x, axis.y, axis.z, 0);

        rotMat = GLKMatrix4MakeWithColumns(tangent0GLK, tangent1GLK, axisGLK, GLKVector4Make(0, 0, 0, 1));
```

Which you can then apply to the transform property of the plane node using multiplication:

```
_node.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(transmat, SCNMatrix4FromGLKMatrix4( rotMat)) );
```

The above is from a project I'm working on, haven't tested it separately. The cross, dot and normalizeVector not included.

Comment: No, I don’t have this in Swift but it is very similar in Swift and probably a little cleaner depending on the math lib you use for vector and matrix math.

Answer (score 1):

THX Xartex for your post. I recoded it in Swift. Just started with Swift, so probably the whole thing could be much more efficient, but it works :)

only one problem appears, the position of the plane also moved, which shouldn't, so I set the old position after the transform action again.

```
  func SCNVector3CrossProduct(left: SCNVector3, right: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3Make(left.y * right.z - left.z * right.y, left.z * right.x - left.x * right.z, left.x * right.y - left.y * right.x)
    }

    func SCNVector3DotProduct(left: SCNVector3, right: SCNVector3) -> float_t {
        return (left.x * right.x + left.y * right.y + left.z * right.z)
    }

    func SCNVektor3Normalize(vector: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
        let scale = 1.0 / sqrt(vector.x*vector.x + vector.y*vector.y + vector.z*vector.z)

        return SCNVector3Make(vector.x * scale, vector.y * scale, vector.z*scale)
    }
    let plane2Node = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
    let plane2Position = SCNVector3(x:0.0, y:0, z:-0.5)
    plane2Node.position = plane2Position


    let normalVector = SCNVector3Make(0.5, 0, 0)
    let transVector1 = SCNVector3Make(1,0,0)
    let transVector2 = SCNVector3Make(0,1,0)
    var tangent0 = SCNVector3CrossProduct(left: normalVector, right: transVector1)
    let dotprod = SCNVector3DotProduct(left: tangent0, right: tangent0)
    if dotprod < 0.001 {
        tangent0 = SCNVector3CrossProduct(left: normalVector, right: transVector2)
    }
    tangent0 = SCNVektor3Normalize(vector: tangent0)

    let helpVector1 = SCNVector3CrossProduct(left: normalVector, right: tangent0)
    let tangent1 = SCNVektor3Normalize(vector: helpVector1)

    let tangent0GLK = GLKVector4Make(tangent0.x, tangent0.y, tangent0.z, 0)
    let tangent1GLK = GLKVector4Make(tangent1.x, tangent1.y, tangent1.z, 0)
    let normalGLK = GLKVector4Make(normalVector.x, normalVector.y, normalVector.z, 0);

    let rotMat = GLKMatrix4MakeWithColumns(tangent0GLK, tangent1GLK, normalGLK, GLKVector4Make(0, 0, 0, 1))
    // transforms the "normal position" of the plane
    let transMat = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(plane2Node.position.x, plane2Node.position.y, plane2Node.position.z);

    plane2Node.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(transMat, SCNMatrix4FromGLKMatrix4( rotMat))

    // position must be set again!
    plane2Node.position = plane2Position

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(plane2Node)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to solve the same problem, this indeed works. Can you explain a little bit of the math behind it, or where can I learn why this is working.